# AlertView Should Disappear On Its Own

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How to make the alertview disappear on its own without using any cancel buttons.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this...

```
-(void)showAlertView
{
   // code for showing your alertView
   [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlertView) withObject:yourObject afterDelay:5]
}

-(void)dismissAlertView
{
    [yourAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks its working..But its disappearing too quick...how to make it stay there for a while.?